# Angular Translate: LocalStorage plugin and requirejs error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I'm using Angular in combination with require.js. In addition to that I use the `angular-translate` addon. Now I added the plugin `angular-translate-storage-local` and I got this error: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $translateCookieStorageProvider <- $translateCookieStorage <- $translateLocalStorage <- $translate`

Usually I would say I forgot to add the dependencies, but I did not (I guess)!

My `requirejs.config`:

```
requirejs.config({
    shim: {
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        ngTranslateLoader: ['ngTranslate'],
        ngTranslateLocalStorage: ['ngTranslate']
    },

    paths: {
        ngTranslate: '../../vendor/angular-translate/angular-translate',
        ngTranslateLoader: '../../vendor/angular-translate-loader-static-files/angular-translate-loader-static-files',
        ngTranslateLocalStorage: '../../vendor/angular-translate-storage-local/angular-translate-storage-local'
    }
});
```

My `module`:

```
define(function(require) {
    require('ngTranslate');
    require('ngTranslateLocalStorage');
    require('ngTranslateLoader');

    var angular = require('angular');

    var app = angular.module('app', [
        'pascalprecht.translate'
    ])
        .config([$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {
            $translateProvider
                .useStaticFilesLoader({
                    prefix: '/language/',
                    suffix: '.json'
                })
                .preferredLanguage('en-DK')
                .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
                .useLocalStorage();
        }]);
});
```

The static file loader plugin works well. Where is my failure?

Edit:
I added following to my `requirejs` config:

```
ngTranslateLocalStorage: ['ngTranslateCookieStorage', 'ngTranslate'],
ngTranslateCookieStorage: ['ngCookies', 'ngTranslate'],
ngCookies: ['angular'],
```

Now I get: `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cookieStoreProvider <- $cookieStore <- $translateCookieStorage <- $translateLocalStorage <- $translate`

If I understand requirejs shim correct it should be enough to `require(ngTranslateLocalStorage)` now, but then I get the message that `pascalprecht.translate` is unknown. If I require all deps although it already done in shim I get the error above. Still something wrong!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service `$translateLocalStorage` depends of `$translateCookieStorage`, which in turns depends of `$cookieStore` from `angular-cookies`.

Therefore, you need to include also `angular-translate-storage-cookie`, `angular-cookies`, and add `ngCookies` in the module dependencies.

To sum up you should have:

```
"angular-translate"
"angular-translate-loader-static-files"
"angular-cookies"
"angular-translate-storage-cookie"
"angular-translate-storage-local"
```

Comment: I tried your answer, but no success. I updated my question.

Comment: Seems you didn't add `ngCookies` in the array of dependencies, when you define `angular.module('app', [...])`

Comment: It works if I `require()` everything. I thought the requirejs shim is handling that for me!?